# ¿Como puedo enviar un input hidden al servidor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola estoy desarrollando una aplicación web con reactjs en su ultima versión, para ello uso la librería Formik para trabajar en forma mas eficiente los formularios de la app, pero tengo un gran problema al querer enviar datos de tipo hidden a mi servidor o ya sea para mostrarlos en la consola del navegador. Puesto que los datos no se envían en el formulario al hacer submit.

A continuación expongo parte de mi código.

```
export class Product extends PureComponent {
displayName = Product.name
setWidth = () => {
    this.props.setWidth("col-12")
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.setWidth()

}
render() {
    const products = [this.props.history.location.state.response.products[0]];
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="Card-Header card-title white-text p-4 center-align">
                <span><i className="fa far fa-user mr-3"></i>Productos</span>
            </div>
            <div className="Card-Main card-content p-4 pt-4">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <div className="Lead mb-4">
                            <p>Seleccione el producto que el cliente devolverá y su cantidad.</p>
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <Formik
                            initialValues={{
                                inputDevolucion: ''
                            }}
                            onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                                console.log("Los valores son (productos): ", values);
                                setSubmitting(false);
                            }}
                            render={props => (
                                <Form>
                                    <table className="striped highlight responsive-table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Còdigo de Barra</th>
                                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                                <th>Validaciòn</th>
                                                <th>Cantidad</th>
                                                <th>Disponible</th>
                                                <th>Precio Unitario</th>
                                                <th>Descuento</th>
                                                <th>Devoluciòn</th>
                                                <th>Comentarios</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    {/* <input type="hidden" name="hiddenCod" defaultValue="5" /> */}
                                                    <InputField
                                                        id="inputDevolucion"
                                                        type="number"
                                                        name="inputDevolucion"
                                                        label="Cantidad"
                                                    />
                                                    <InputField
                                                        id="inputHidden"
                                                        type="hidden"
                                                        name="inputHidden"
                                                    />
                                                </td>
                                                <td></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <div className="center-align mt-5">
                                        <Raised isSubmit={true} text="Siguiente" isIcon={false}></Raised>
                                    </div>
                                </Form>
                            )}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="Card-Footer card-action p-0 pt-4">
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

es un componen que cree en base al componente nativo por decirlo de formik. Ya aca es donde tengo el problema, si se dan cuenta tengo mi input hidden y un input text, con el ultimo no hay problemas, pero con el hidden es donde comienzan estos... no eh dado la forma de hacer que se envíen los datos de este campo.

A todo esto lo necesito para recorrer una lista y enviar algunos datos dinámicos al servidor en el campo hidden.

Si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería.

Comment: Nunca he trabajado con formik, pero creo que deberías setear un valor inicial para `inputHidden` en `initialValues`

Comment: He probado de todas las formas posibles y nada...